# Get selected items from multi selection combobox

Tags: angular, typescript, vmware-clarity

I have a combobox from Clarity Design which allows to choose more than one option and I would like to get the selected items by clicking a button. I couldn't find anything that I could apply to this specific case, so it would be nice if anyone could give me some ideas about how to do it.

This is the HTML from the combobox:

```
   <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="getSelected()">Button</button >
   <clr-combobox [(ngModel)]="selection" name="multiSelect" clrMulti="true" required>
      <ng-container *clrOptionSelected="let selected">{{selected}}</ng-container>
      <clr-options>
         <clr-option *clrOptionItems="let opt of options; field:'selected'" [clrValue]="opt">
            {{opt}}
         </clr-option>
      </clr-options>
   </clr-combobox>
```

[Combobox with 2 selected options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xANgY.jpg)

Comment: You already have it in your component. `selection`. That is your `[(ngModel)]`. What else are you expecting from `clr-combobox`?

Comment: At the time I did not know how to use the ngModel, as I was new in Angular. Thanks for your response anyway!